# вырезать из текста слова которые написаны заглавными буквами javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

```
ЭтО теКст КОТОРЫЙ нужно ОБРЕЗАТЬ
```

Как из данного текста вырезать слова которые написаны заглавными буквами?

```
КОТОРЫЙ ОБРЕЗАТЬ
```

Знаю как обрезать буквы заглавные но как вырезать слова не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно при помощи [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```js
const str = 'ЭтО теКст КОТОРЫЙ нужно ОБРЕЗАТЬ 123';

// Одна или несколько заглавных букв и цифры в окружении не-букв.
const upperCaseRegexp = /(?<!\p{L})(?:\p{N}+|\p{Lu}+)(?!\p{L})/gu;

const upperCaseWords = str.match(upperCaseRegexp) || [];

console.log(upperCaseWords.join(' ')); // 'КОТОРЫЙ ОБРЕЗАТЬ 123'
```

Удаляем одиночные заглавные буквы:

```js
const str = 'ТЕКСТ ЭТОТ Д В ТЕСТОВЫЙ';

// Одна заглавная  бува в окружении не-букв.
const upperCaseSingleLetters = /(?<!\p{L})\p{Lu}(?!\p{L})/gu;

const noUpperCaseSingleLetters = str.replace(upperCaseSingleLetters, '')
                                    .replace(/  +/, ' '); // Сокращаем пробелы.

console.log(noUpperCaseSingleLetters); // 'ТЕКСТ ЭТОТ ТЕСТОВЫЙ'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А не подскажите еще как вырезать еденичные буквы, например в таком тесте нужно убрать В и Д
``` ТЕКСТ ЭТОТ Д В ТЕСТОВЫЙ``` что бы получилось ``` ТЕКСТ ЭТОТ ТЕСТОВЫЙ```

Comment: И можно ли в этой регулярке что вы предоставили сделать что бы еще цифры выводило, заранее спасибо  )

Comment: Отредактировал пример для включения чисел и добавил пример для удаления одиночных заглавных букв.

Comment: Очень Вам благодарен )

Comment: Не хотели бы Вы мне помочь на возмездной основе? У меня есть задача по регуляркам, если поможете отблагодарю

Comment: К сожалению, у меня фрагментарные знания и непредсказуемое свободное время, так что я вам не смогу быть надёжно полезен. Попробуйте поискать кого-то на фриланс-бирже, будет наверняка лучше и проще)

Comment: Может вы знаете как вот тут https://codepen.io/sanyacastor/pen/xxOyqLZ?editors=1011 вытянуть фио? Буду Вам очень признателен  )

Comment: Простите, не знаю) Эти тексты после распознавания настолько аморфны, что я даже не представляю, как к ним подступиться.